# Yacc actions return 0 for any variable ($)

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I'm new to Lex/Yacc. Found these [lex](http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) & [yacc](http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y-2011.html) files which parse ansi C.

To experiment I added an action to print part of the parsing:

```
constant
    : I_CONSTANT    { printf("I_CONSTANT %d\n", $1); }
    | F_CONSTANT
    | ENUMERATION_CONSTANT  /* after it has been defined as such */
    ;
```

The problem is, no matter where I put the action, and whatever $X I use, I always get value 0.

Here I got printed:

```
I_CONSTANT 0
```

Even though my input is:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return 5;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: For `I_CONSTANT` the lexer returns the actual value through `yylval`? Perhaps you should consider a few tutorials about Lex and Yacc first?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the lex file you point to actually sets semantic values for any token. As the author says, the files are just a grammar and "the bulk of the work" still needs to be done. (There are other caveats having to do with the need for a preprocessor.)

Since nothing in the lex file ever sets `yylval`, it will always be 0, and that is what yacc/bison will find when it sets up the semantic value for the token (`$1` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `yylval = atoi(yytext)` is not done in the lex file, so I had to add it myself. Also learned I can add `extern char *yytext` to the yacc file header, and then use `yytext` directly.

Comment: Do not use `yytext` in your bison file. It will generally not have the correct value (even if it seems to work in one particular case.) And don't suggest to anyone else that they do so. It"s a big bad bug in waiting.